# How to import statically all variables at the same time in eclipse when use "Add import" in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, import

For example i have ConstantsClass.java with :

```
private static final String DUMMY_STRING = "dummy string";
```

and MyClass.java :

```
import net.foo.ConstantsClass;

public void doStuff(){
  String value = ConstantsClass.DUMMY_STRING ;
  doStuff2(ConstantsClass.DUMMY_STRING);
}
```

When i add a static import for the first DUMMY_STRING with "Add Import"(Ctrl+Shift+M), i will  have

```
import static net.foo.ConstantsClass.DUMMY_STRING;
import net.foo.ConstantsClass;

public void doStuff(){
  String value = DUMMY_STRING ;
  doStuff2(ConstantsClass.DUMMY_STRING);
}
```

If i want to do it for all variables in this class, i have to make "Add import" for each "DUMMY_STRING", is there a way to do it for all "DUMMY_STRING" in one command ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the preference. Find **Java -> Code Style -> Organize Imports** and change the value of ***Number of static imports needed for .**** to '1'

[image]

Comment: That's not what i search for, i want to import statically all the same static variables at the same time, instead of do a "add import" for each static variables one by one ?